# Laravel PHP 4: 'Put' method generates 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException'

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to modify a form used for editing and updating data.  However when I try submitting the 'edit' form, I keep getting a 'MethodNotAllowedHttpException'.  I'm not sure if this is because I am using the 'PUT' method incorrectly or my 'EditAlbumsController.php' file is not defined correctly.

**edit-album.blade.php:**

```
{{ Form::model($album, array('method' => 'PUT', 'route' => array('edit_album', $album->album_id))) }}
/* Form code here */
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**routes.php:**

```
Route::get('gallery/album/{id}/edit', array('as'=>'edit_album', 'uses'=>'EditAlbumsController@update'));
```

**EditAlbumsController.php:**

```
class EditAlbumsController extends AlbumsController {

public function __construct() 
{
    parent::__construct();
}

public function update($id)
{
    $input = \Input::except('_method');

    $validation = new Validators\Album($input);

    if ($validation->passes())
    {
    $album = Album::find($id);
    $album->album_name = $input['album_name'];
    /* Additional database fields go here */
    $album->touch();
    return $album->save();

    return \Redirect::route('gallery.album.show', array('id' => $id));
    }
    else
    {
        return \Redirect::route('gallery.album.edit', array('id' => $id))
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation->errors)
        ->with('message', \Lang::get('gallery::gallery.errors'));
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the PUT route (you are incorrectly using GET)

```
Route::put('gallery/album/{id}/edit', array('as'=>'edit_album', 'uses'=>'EditAlbumsController@update'));
```